# how do i highlight a selected text and store in db and when the page reloads highlight back the selected text?

Tags: javascript, html

I am able to store the highlighted text .how do i highlight the text back when the page loads back ?

here is the sample code :

```
$(document).mouseup(function(event){

  highlighterOn = true;
    if (highlighterOn){

    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    var sel = range.extractContents();
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    span.appendChild(sel);
    range.insertNode(span);

  }
});
```

Comment: Instead of reloading the page can you just use AJAX? You are already using jQuery ($), right?

Comment: @Gotschi Highlighting != selecting

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the code above, but I would suggest (since you have already stored the highlighted text in a database of some kind) is just to select the innerHTML of the div and do something like `.replace('the text I want to highlight','<span class="highlighted">the text I want to highlight</span>')` and then style the .highlighted class with CSS.